# Android OnClickListener complexity

Tags: java, android, complexity-theory, onclicklistener

I need to know, what is better in terms of complexity. Either to identity a separate onClick method from xml for each button like this:

```
android:onClick:"clickHandler"
```

and the java code:

```
public void clickHandler(View v){ 
         Button b = (Button) v;
         //do something for that button
      };
```

, or identify one method for all of the buttons, and separate them with if conditions.

```
Public void clickHandler(View v){
      Button b = (Button) v; 
      if(b.getText().equals("a")){
      }
         elseif(b.getText().equals("b")){
            }
       //And so on.
    }
```

I am not that good in calculating complexity and so on, but this question just irritates and I can't answer it. But what I understand, the first method increases the code lines a lot!

Comment: Why not using different handlers for each button?

Comment: This is the 1st method!, I am just asking between the different between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally like the latter. Except I tend to do something that looks more like this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
   switch(v.getId()){
      case R.id.button_a:
        //do button a logic here
        break;
      case R.id.button_b:
        //do button b logic here
        break;
   }
}
```

Consider making your `Activity implement View.OnClickListener` than in your `OnCreate()` simple attach with `findViewById(R.id.button_a).setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: Yea I know the way that implements View.OnClickListener but it's not possible in this application due to different aspects.

Comment: @user1219909 I'm curious, what would prevent you from having your activity extend it?

Comment: There are TOO many views, and I am not giving them IDs.So, it's only from the XML code, I assign them clickHandlers.

Comment: Ok. Well the `switch` statement is most certainly a better option then `b.getText().equals("a");`. In fact its much much better to have individual ids then doing a series of `String` compares which will be slower. Consider the performance of a block of if-else statements of String compares to a switch statement of IDs. That is one of the reasons this option is by far better.
Some other food for thought: if you have tons of clickable buttons on a single page, is this a good UX for the user?

Comment: Yeahh it's designed for tablet users. There are several layouts that appears and disappears. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using `Fragment`s? They should break up the complexity out of a single `Activity` as to avoid this issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a version of the second option.  Create one handler, and then use a switch statement to determine which view received the event.  It is code efficient and is not messy at all.  Also, you don't need to list that attribute in xml... I personally think it is much easier to findViewById() in your activity and implement onClickListener.  Then you can use each button's id in your switch statement.